# How to remove a gap between nodes in a GridPane caused by different-sized nodes?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a number pad with a clear and start button, but because the clear and start button are wider than the number buttons, there's a gap between the first two columns. Here's a picture:

Numberpad with a gap between the first two columns:

[image: numberpad]

I've tried looking up answers, but I haven't found anything like this. It's kinda hard to explain to a search engine.

I expected the 0 button to align with the middle of the numpad (which it does), with the clear and start buttons sticking out on both sides. But it aligned the clear button with the 7 button, causing the gap. Here's a reproducible example:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ReproducibleGap extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new ButtonGrid());
        
        primaryStage.setTitle("Numpad");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class ButtonGrid extends GridPane {

    protected Button[] numpad = new Button[10];
    protected Button clear;
    protected Button start;

    ButtonGrid() {
        Font buttonFont = new Font(18);
        for (int i = 0; i < numpad.length; i++) {
            numpad[i] = new Button(String.valueOf(i));
            numpad[i].setFont(buttonFont);
        }

        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setPadding(new Insets(50, 0, 0, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            addRow(i, numpad[i * 3 + 1], numpad[i * 3 + 2], numpad[i * 3 + 3]);
        }

        clear = new Button("Clear");
        clear.setFont(buttonFont);

        start = new Button("Start");
        start.setFont(buttonFont);

        addRow(3, clear, numpad[0], start);
    }
}
```

Comment: Vbox of HBoxes with alignment on the vbox set to center, but there are other options if you prefer.  For instance, you can set halignment on individual cells in a GridPane.  SceneBuilder is good for prototyping layouts, even if you decide not to use FXML.

Comment: "_with the clear and start buttons sticking out on both sides_" -- If I understand this correctly, then you simply need to configure the nodes in the first column to align to the right when there's empty space. You can do this for the entire column via a [`ColumnConstraints`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html) or for individual nodes via [`GridPane#setHalignment(Node, HPos)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setHalignment(javafx.scene.Node,javafx.geometry.HPos)).

Comment: _It's kinda hard to explain to a search engine_ a good first step in research is the api doc https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html :) That's for learning which configuration options are available specifically the class you want to use. Another good stepping stone is are - here: layout - tutorials (the javafx tag wiki has references).

Comment: btw: layout classes are meant for using, not for extending - actually, it's a general rule: never-ever extend if you can achieve the same by configuration

Comment: Can you be more specific about the layout you actually want? If you just want the numeric buttons to expand so there is no gap, that is essentially covered in the [standard Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/size_align.htm): use `numpad[i].setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);` and `GridPane.setFillWidth(numpad[i], true);`. If you want the columns to be the same width, use [`ColumnConstraints`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html) with `percentWidth` set. If you want something else, explain...

Comment: @kleopatra Well, shoot, the textbook I was reading extended panes, so I thought that was what you were supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

> "with the clear and start buttons sticking out on both sides" -- If I understand this correctly, then you simply need to configure the nodes in the first column to align to the right when there's empty space. You can do this for the entire column via a ColumnConstraints or for individual nodes via GridPane#setHalignment(Node, HPos) -Slaw

Thank you so much! I added:

```java
ColumnConstraints column0 = new ColumnConstraints();
column0.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
getColumnConstraints().add(column0);
```

and now it looks like this:

[image: The first column is now aligned to the right, removing the gap]

which is how I wanted!